# chrome extension message passing empty div

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message

I'm trying to pass a div from a content script as a message to my `background.js` of a chrome extension, in accordance with what's [described officially here by Google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Code to consider is fairly simple:

**Relevant part of `manifest.json`:**

```
{
  "name": "Proof of conecpt extension",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab", "storage","tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/lib/jquery.1.9.0.min.js", "js/content.js"],
    "css": ["css/style.css"]
  }],
  "background":{"scripts":["js/background.js"]},
}
```

**`content.js`:**

```
window.onload = function() //init
{
  div = document.querySelector("div"); //get the first div in each page for example
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({firstDiv: div.innerHTML});
  console.log("message sent.");
}
```

**`background.js`:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( //receive messages 
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    console.log(request);
  });
```

This works as expected most of the time, and I see the the first div innerHTML messages that passes from the content scripts. However, On StackOverfow.com for example, I get this output on the background script console:

```
from a content script:http://stackoverflow.com/
Object {firstDiv: ""}
```

Message passes, but it seems the first div is empty. This is obviously false information, because when I use Chrome's devtools and manually type "div" in console with the extension context, I see:

```
<div id="notify-container"></div>
```

Why is this happening? Is this a security feature?

Comment: You need to use `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML

Comment: Silly me. You're right. Thanks! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an empty string because [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) returns the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants, and in this case the `div` has no descendants. If you want to include the parent element in the HTML returned you should use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) instead.